# A question on DAC and sampling

Tags: dac

A traducer's analog output is generated by its DAC as seen in the below plots. The plots are from the same data with increasing zoom. Plots obtained by using a DAQ. It seems like the DAC outputs 3 voltage values per second(see the last plot). But it is raw and not filtered and thus not smooth. It looks like this transducer doesn't filter/smooth the DAC output. It is in discrete steps not smooth as you see(created by samplehold of DAC).

I have couple of questions:

1-) Is a smoothing filter needed if I am only interested in the mean value of the voltages? Is filter only needed in applications like sound outputs?

2-) I'm sampling this DAC output by a DAQ device(sampling rate 500Hz) and obtain the below plots. What would you say about the noise here? Is that something to do with sampling rates or DAC being not smoothed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Theoretically speaking, you generally want a reconstruction filter on the output of your DAC; a simple example, say you know your Max DAC output frequency will be 500Hz, you can put a simple low-pass filter on the output to suppress harmonics / HF noise

Comment: are the harmonics coming from sampehold of the DAC?

Comment: what R C values would you recommend for low pass?

Comment: @KrunalDesai: For some purposes, frequency component above Nyquist is undesirable and should be squelched.  For other purposes, however, one wants an output which switches quickly between discrete values.  What kind of filter one should use will depend upon what one wants the output to do.

Comment: @supercat in which purpose one may want output with switching discrete values?

Comment: @user16307: When outputting an analog video output to display discrete-pixel graphics and fonts.  Hard pixels look bad when the frequency content of the source contains things that are near Nyquist or a multiple thereof, but they look better than fuzzy pixels when everything in the source aligns with precise submultiples of Nyquist.  One can legibly show R rows of C hex digits on a 4C by 6R display, but only if the pixels show up discretely.  The spectral content of the source will in many cases be concentrated at odd multiples of Nyquist, so anti-aliasing filtering would totally kill it.

Answer (score 1):

A good calculator page for RC filter and analytics is:
  http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRlowkeisan.htm

Better yet, go for an active filter using an opamp.  A Salen Key calculator is:
  http://www.calculatoredge.com/electronics/sk%20low%20pass.htm

Comment: What is the advantage of active filter compring. to passive filter?